What values can Environment.SystemDirectory return?
According to this, the signature of the Environment.SystemDirectory is:
public static string SystemDirectory { get; }

Obviously this will return a string, but my question is, given the variety of OSs that .Net Core now runs on, are there any cases in which the return value could be an empty string?  Or will the returned value be guaranteed (as much as you can) to be a non-zero length string?
The reason I am asking, is that I am seeing code like this:
string path = Environment.SystemDirectory;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
{
  ...
}


Quickly glancing at code shows that this returns non-empty string for Windows and OSX. Linux for example doesn't have centralized OS directory, as everything is scattered in file system root

@JL0PD I was going to point to that code, but IMHO all that does is push my question down a level to "GetFolderPathCore()".    But I also have no idea about the behavior under Linux.  At the very worst case, the top most level directory under Linux would be "/".  (Finally I am suspicious of that filename "Environment.UnixOrBrowser.cs" )

Empty string by default in Linux, both by root and non-root users (Manjaro Linux).

I believe SystemDirectory is not relevant term for Linux. Empty string is just fallback value.

Environment.SystemDirectory should always have the same behavior as Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System, Environment.SpecialFolderOption.None)
On Windows:
Equivalents to GetSystemDirectoryW which is never empty
On macOS:
Always returns "/System"
On all other platforms:
Always returns string.Empty
